# Having trouble understanding the output of code when dealing with pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, output

This is a practice question from my coding final.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 3

// a structure type for storing an array. 
typedef struct
{
    int *ptrData;
    int length;
} ARRAY;

void printArray(ARRAY A)
{
    int i;
    printf("Array Content:\n");
    for (i=0; i<A.length; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", A.ptrData[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int x[N]={1, 3, 5};
    ARRAY array1;
    ARRAY array2;
    array1.ptrData=x;
    array1.length=N;
    array2=array1;
    array1.ptrData[0]=10;
    printArray(array1);
    printArray(array2);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
Array Content:
10
3
5
Array Content:
10
3
5
```

I am having trouble understanding why the output for `array2` is the same as `array1`. I understand how they got the values for `array1` but not sure for `array2` since, from my understanding, the first element of the `array1` was changed to 10 after declaring `array1 = array2`  but from the output, it seems like `array2`'s first element was set to 10 as well.

If would like clarification on why the output of `array2` is the same as `array1`.

Comment: Because they point to the same array, of which there is only one. So change that and it doesn't matter which `struct` you access it through.

Comment: Try printing the value of `ptrData` in both the arrays. You will understand.

Comment: ...in both the `struct`s ;)

Comment: Because when you copy the structs, you don't "hard copy" the contents, so each struct's pointer will still point at the same location and neither struct "owns" the pointed-at data.

Answer (score 3):

This is your struct:

```
typedef struct {
    int *ptrData;
    int length;
} ARRAY;
```

and here, you assign one instance of the struct to another:

```
array2=array1;
```

This copies all fields, but the field `ptrData` is only a *pointer* to the number array instance. This is also called a *shallow copy*, because it only creates copies the fields of the struct itself, but not of the referenced objects it might contain (as opposed to a deep-copy, which cannot be done with c primitives). So the number array instance is not duplicated, only the pointer to it. As a consequence the array only exists once, and modification is reflected regardless if you access it through the struct instance `array1` or `array2`.

The situation would be different if you have a struct

```
typedef struct {
    int data[N];
    int length;
} ARRAY;
```

Here, indeed two instances of the array content `data` exist and the data would be *copied* on assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Because both of array1 and array2 pointing to same (x)

You can check this by printing values of x by

```
for (i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    printf("%d\n", x[i]);
}
```

Here also value of x[0] will be changed

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct
{
    int *ptrData;
    int length;
} ARRAY;
```

Here `ptrData` is a pointer which points a memory address.

```
array1.ptrData=x;
```

This line sets the memory which is pointed by the pointer member of `array1` struct as start address of array `x`. The name of an array is also a pointer thus here this assignment can be done without any error.

```
array2=array1;
```

This line copies all information hold by `array1` to `array2`. This means `array2.ptrData = array1.ptrData` and `array2.length = array1.length`.
Then `array2.ptrData` pointer points the same memory with `array1.ptrData` pointer. You can access the same memory address using these two pointers.